# Programmatically create a new Table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to create an empty datatable that will later get filled by the user.
Is there a way to do so, and then check to see, if a table was created?

I've already tried it out with an access DB and got it to work, but in my case it would make more sense to do it inside the program itself.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.  Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: there sadly is nothing to show so far, i've tried some copy paste codes in order to set up the new datatable, expecting to find it afterwards in my DB-Explorer - but i did not

Comment: What database engine do you want to use? Each tends to have its own variations on the `CREATE TABLE` SQL command...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the kind of forum that fits for these kinds of questions, MSDN Forum is better in this case. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty datatable with this syntax:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable   ' Create the empty datatable

dt.Columns.Add("ColumnNameHere", GetType(Int32)) ' Add a column called "ColumnNameHere" that holds integer values
```

You can add as many columns as you need to match your database table. Also here is a list of valid data types that you can use to define your columns (you may have to do more reading to ensure that you match the right VB.Net data type with your databases data type).

- Boolean
- Byte
- Char
- DateTime
- Decimal
- Double
- Guid
- Int16
- Int32
- Int64
- SByte
- Single
- String
- TimeSpan
- UInt16
- UInt32
- UInt64

Comment: You know sir, if the user who didn't tried so far will downvote an answer that doesn't fit them..